# Django how to do a conditional redirect after POST?

Tags: django, redirect

I have a form that displays some of the fields in the user profile among other things. In this form the fields from the profile are disabled. If the details are outdated the user can go to the edit profile view and update the details. For this, I included a button in the template of the form. After updating the profile I want the user to return to the form. This last part is the one I am having problems with.

The link to edit the profile from the form looks like:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'profile'%}?next={% url 'submission_resume' %}">Edit Profile</a>
```

This is how the url looks comming from the form:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profile/?next=/submissions/resume/
```

The problem is that in the edit profile view I do not know how to implement the conditional redirect:

```
def profile(request):
    """ View and edit the profile. It requires user to be login """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserModifyForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            #??? if next in url go back to the form ???
            #??? return redirect(???) ???
            #??? else: ???
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UserModifyForm(instance=request.user)
 #--> Dict for template with the forms
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
 #--> Show profile page
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', context)   
#---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work by changing the view to:

```
def profile(request):
    """ View and edit the profile. It requires user to be login """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserModifyForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            redirect_to = request.POST['redirect_to']
            return redirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        redirect_to = request.GET.get("next", "profile")
        form = UserModifyForm(instance=request.user)
 #--> Dict for template with the forms
    context = {
        'redirect_to': redirect_to,
        'form'       : form,
    }
 #--> Show profile page
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', context)   
#---
```

and in the template including:

```
<input type="hidden" name='redirect_to' value="{{redirect_to}}">
```

inside the `<form>` tag

But still I wonder if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Could you please give your requirement a little clearly, Is it whenever the form is edited and saved, you wanted to redirect the user to the 'next' page and whenever there isn't any form submission you wanted to redirect the user to the default page.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Pradeep The user starts filling the form and realized that the contact details shown in the form are outdated so he clicks in a button in the form that takes the user to the profile edit page. The user finishes editing the profile and hit submit to save the changes in the profile. If the user arrived at the edit profile page from the form, the pages redirects the user back to the form after saving the changes. If not coming from the form show the profile with the new values.

Comment: You can use "return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))" in your views.py after saving the form to redirect the user to their previous page

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, but it is not just going back. If the user is on the home page and decides to update the profile then after updating I want the user to stay on the profile page. If the user is in the form and decide to update the profile then it is going back.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
redirect_to = request.POST.get("next", "profile")
return redirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: Did the user data change when you submit the form and the only problem is redirecting? Maybe you are sending a `GET` request to your view.

Comment: Yes the user profile is updated. The redirect is the only problem

Answer (score 0):

```
request.POST.get('redirect_to', None))
```

The above statement will give the redirect_to value if it present, else it will return  'None'

so you can try

```
request.POST.get('redirect_to', 'replace the value with default view where you want to redirect'))
```

You can also try below code if you simply want to redirect to the previous page

```
 redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: The problem is how to include the redirect_to in the post variables. The going back option is also not enough as explained in one of the comments to my answer